# PHP Foreach save ID

Tags: php, xml

I have so called "GAEB" files, which are in XML structure.
I loop through these via foreach and simplexml.

XML/GAEB File:

```
<GAEB>
  <Award>
    <BoQ>
      <BoQBody>
        <BoQCtgy RNoPart="01">
          <BoQBody>
            <BoQCtgy RNoPart="01">
              <BoQBody>
                <BoQCtgy>
                  <BoQBody RNoPart="01">
                    <Itemlist>
                      <Item RNoPart="1">
                      <Item RNoPart="2">
                    </Itemlist>
                  </BoQBody>
                </BoQCtgy>
                <BoQCtgy>
                  <BoQBody RNoPart="02">
                    <Itemlist>
                      <Item RNoPart="1">
                      <Item RNoPart="2">
                    </Itemlist>
                  </BoQBody>
                </BoQCtgy>
              </BoQBody>
            </BoQCtgy>
            <BoQCtgy RNoPart="02">
              <BoQBody>
                <BoQCtgy>
                  <BoQBody RNoPart="01">
                    <Itemlist>
                      <Item RNoPart="1">
                      <Item RNoPart="2">
                    </Itemlist>
                  </BoQBody>
                </BoQCtgy>
                <BoQCtgy>
                  <BoQBody RNoPart="02">
                    <Itemlist>
                      <Item RNoPart="1">
                      <Item RNoPart="2">
                    </Itemlist>
                  </BoQBody>
                </BoQCtgy>
              </BoQBody>
            </BoQCtgy>
          </BoQBody>
        </BoQCtgy>
      </BoQBody>
    </BoQ>
  </Award>
</GAEB>
```

My PHP Code Loops through all $xml->BoQBody->BoQCtgy till it finds a Itemlist.
Then looping through that Itemlist and get some informations from there.
After that start loop again.

PHP:

```
<?php
$file = "pathtoxmlfile";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

function loop($path, $xml){
  foreach($path->BoQBody->BoQCtgy as $BoQCtgy){
    $nr = $BoQCtgy->attributes()["RNoPart"];
    echo $nr;      

    if(ISSET($BoQCtgy->BoQBody->Itemlist) === TRUE{
      foreach($BoQCtgy->BoQBody->Itemlist->Item as $item){
        $pos = $item->attributes()["RNoPart"];
        echo $pos;
      }
    }
  }
  loop($BoQCtgy,$xml);
}

loop($xml->Award->BoQ,$xml);
?>
```

How I get a clear numbering of all my positions?
The above example should be:

```
01
01.01
01.01.01
01.01.01.1
01.01.01.2
01.01.02
01.01.02.1
01.01.02.2
```

The problem is, the deepth is everytime a other.
I get all positions and all values I need with the PHP Code without any problems.
But I can't get a matching numbering...

Hope somebody knows a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XPath you don't have to worry about what depth items are at.  In this case it first looks for any node with an `RNoPart` attribute using `//*[@RNoPart]`...

- // - any level
- any node
- [@RNoPart] - with a RNoPart attribute (the `@` indicates an attribute)

It loops over the results and then uses the `ancestor` axes in XPath to look for all parent elements with another RNoPart attribute, using `ancestor::*/@RNoPart`.

As it loops over these (in this example) it just outputs the values followed by a `.` and a new line after each sub set.

So put together, you get...

```
foreach ( $xml->xpath("//*[@RNoPart]") as $part )   {
    foreach ( $part['RNoPart']->xpath("ancestor::*/@RNoPart") as $part )   {
        echo $part.".";
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

and with your sample XML, outputs...

```
01.
01.01.
01.01.01.
01.01.01.1.
01.01.01.2.
01.01.02.
01.01.02.1.
01.01.02.2.
01.02.
01.02.01.
01.02.01.1.
01.02.01.2.
01.02.02.
01.02.02.1.
01.02.02.2.
```

Comment: After a few tests I found out that some part numbers have a leading space.
For example all Items have four digits, two of them I get via your code and the other two are leading spaces.
I tried with ifs to check if the actual foreach position is a "Item" but came to no success.

Comment: The leading space came from the gaeb file and have to be there.
The number of spaces are saved in a variable. So the RNoPart could be:
" 01. 01. 01.   1"
The first spaces are not a problem, but the Item itself got a other count of spaces.

Comment: I can't show that clearly.
The gaeb file itself needs sometimes leading spaces (two, three, four spaces, etc.).
I get the count of spaces from a variable in the gaeb file, this already works.
But if there is a Item, e.g. `01.01.01.1.` is a Item, then the Item Number is ` 01. 01. 01.    1.` and not `01.01.01.1.`.

Stackoverflow edit my spaces itself... Therefore I can't show that clearly.

Comment: If you just want to remove the spaces `echo trim($part).".";`

Comment: I have to add spaces, not removing them.

Comment: If you need to pad - use `str_pad($part, $length," ", STR_PAD_LEFT);` for each part.

Comment: Yes thats right but not the solution.
If I use this, all positions get the same number of spaces.
But thats wrong, if the last number is a Item, then there are a other count of spaces. Only Items got an other spacecount. Not a BoQBody...

Comment: Please ask this as another question as there seem to be a few parts to it and it's difficult to sort out in comments.